# Social Security Number input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have [**this**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNrjWe) sample:

```js
function ssnFormat() {
  $("#ssn").on('blur change', function() {
    text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$3-$2-$4");
    if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val().match(text) || $(this).val().length == 0) {
      $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
  });
}

$("#ssn").on('blur change', function() {
  ssnFormat();
});
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="required-input" id="ssn" maxlength="9" type="text" name="ssn" placeholder="123-45-6789">
```

What I want to do these things are:

1. If I write the following text I want to validate this format `123-12-1234`
2. If I write `123456789` I want to transform when click outside input in this format

   123-12-1234

I tried to do this by using the function below but don't work

```
$("#ssn").on("click", function() {
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        var value = thisVal.replace(/[^\/\d]/g,''); //here is a problem
        $(this).val(value);
    });
```

Can you please help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```js
function myFunc() {
   var patt = new RegExp("\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{4}");
   var x = document.getElementById("ssn");
   var res = patt.test(x.value);
   if(!res){
    x.value = x.value
        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
        .replace(/-*$/g, '');
   }
}
```

```css
.valid{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input class="required-input" id="ssn" type="text" name="ssn" placeholder="123-45-6789" onBlur = "myFunc()">
```

Also there is another way to enforce user always enters that pattern -

```
<input class="required-input" id="ssn" type="text" name="ssn" placeholder="123-45-6789" onBlur = "myFunc()" required pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{4}">
```

Comment: to me it does not work, you can put pen please link to code if you work?

Comment: Unexpected token .

Comment: @JohnSmith there's an superflous `.` in the code after `thisVal`, I've submitted an edit.

Comment: please try to put in the correct format first.Ex: 123-12-1234

Comment: ok but you remove character limit ... user is not allowed to write more characters than needed

Comment: - also counted in your 9 length limit

Comment: I had to escape the backslashes to get this working. So here is the regex: `new RegExp("\\d{3}[\-]\\d{2}[\-]\\d{4}")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunc() {
   var patt = new RegExp("\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{4}");
   var x = document.getElementById("ssn");
   var res = patt.test(x.value);
   if(!res){
    x.value = x.value
        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
        .replace(/-*$/g, '');
   }
}
```

```css
.valid{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.invalid{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input class="required-input" id="ssn" type="text" name="ssn" placeholder="123-45-6789" onBlur = "myFunc()">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.