# Javascript RegEx for Pattern Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex

This should be easy. I have the following code:

```
var patt = new RegExp("\d{3}[\-]\d{1}");
var res = patt.test(myelink_account_val);
if(!res){
  alert("Inputs must begin with something like XXX-X of numbers and a dash!");
  return;
}
```

Basically, forcing users to enter something like 101-4 . The code is borrowed from [Social Security Number input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074856/social-security-number-input-validation) . And I can confirm that my inputs are indeed like 101-4; only the first five characters need to fit the pattern.

But running my code always gives the alert--the condition is never matched.

Must be something simple?!

Thanks.

Comment: Use `var patt = /^\d{3}-\d$/` if the whole input should match the pattern. If it should only  start with it, use `var patt = /^\d{3}-\d/`

Comment: If you create a regexp using a string then you need to escape the `\ ` so you have to write `\\d `

Comment: `/^\d{3}-\d{1}$/`  .... um basically what he wrote

Comment: @t.niese solution works--by escaping with another \ . Thanks.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped)

Comment: Maybe a 'duplicate' as in hindsight. Unfortunately, the StackOverflow example I had followed literally didn't help--and hence a repost. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "new RegExp" you are passing it a string.

Two solutions here:

1) Don't use "new RegExp()", but a regexp pattern:

```
var patt = /\d{3}[\-]\d{1}/
```

2) If you want to use it, remember you will have to escape the escapes:

```
var patt = new RegExp("\\d{3}[\\-]\\d{1}");
```

Also, remember, if a '-' is the only symbol (or first, or last) on a [], you can skip the escape:

```
var patt = new RegExp("\\d{3}[-]\\d{1}");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var patt = new RegExp("^\\d{3}[\\-]\\d{1}");
console.log(patt.test("123-4"));
console.log(patt.test("123-456"));
console.log(patt.test("12-4"));
console.log(patt.test("abc-d"));
```